# How to get the selected option of <form:select>?

Tags: spring-mvc, html-select

```
<c:forEach var="bu" items="${brand.businessUnits}">
    <td class="dataText">
        <c:if test="${bu.marketCode == masterMarket}">
            <c:out value="${param.id}"></c:out>
            <form:select disabled='${disableDisplayType}' path="categories[${bu.marketCode}].categoryDisplayTypeId" cssClass="selectLrg">
                <form:option value="" />
                <form:options items="${categoryDisplayTypes}" itemLabel="name" itemValue="id" />
            </form:select>
            <c:out value="${param.id}"></c:out>
            <form:errors path="categories[${bu.marketCode}].categoryDisplayTypeId" cssClass="error" />
            <c:if test="${disableDisplayType}">
                <form:hidden path="categories[${bu.marketCode}].categoryDisplayTypeId" />
            </c:if>
        </c:if>
    </td>
</c:forEach>
```

Here I want to get the categoryDisplayType based on selected from dropdown control.

Answer (score 0):

$('#**formName** select[name="**pathName**"] option:selected').val();